# Continuous bijection from open n- ball to closed n- ball

Tags: general-topology

Does there exist a continuous bijection from open n ball to closed n-ball? One with a simple argument can show that no such function exists for n=1.But, what about n>1?

Comment: For those who arrive later, the case $n=1$ is discussed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42308/continuous-bijection-from-0-1-to-0-1).

Answer (score 7):

No. This is a special case of Brouwer's theorem of [invariance of domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).

Comment: Is there a simpler proof for the special case in the question? In particular, for $n=2$?

Comment: Not that I can see as yet. You only need the original Jordan curve theorem, rather than the $n$-dimensional generalization, but that's not much gain.

Comment: Another way: the continuous image of a compact set (the closed ball) must be compact (which the open ball is not).

Comment: @Samuel: That's the opposite direction of what's being considered here.

Comment: @Chris, I meant a simpler proof for the case of an open disk in the plane, not a general open set.

Comment: @lhf: yes, I gathered that.