# is the real line homeomorphic to the curve $\sqrt{x}$

Tags: general-topology

is the real line homeomorphic to the curve $\sqrt{x}$? I think no because of origin in $\sqrt{x}$. it's bounded on left but R is not bounded? is it just?

Comment: Real line for example is homeomorphic to open interval $(0,1)$ which is bounded.

Comment: The curve $\sqrt{x}$ has a boundary point; the real line does not. That’s the real issue; you may be trying to say that, but “bounded” means something else.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes, I understand. Poor terminology from me sorry. so $\sqrt{x}$ without (0,0) is homeomorphic to real line?

Comment: Somehow related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240414/is-there-exist-a-homemoorphism-between-either-pair-of-0-1-0-1-0-1

Comment: @Loli Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac 1 {\pi} (\pi /2+\arctan x)$ is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R$ to $(0,1)$. $x \to \frac x {1-x}$ is  a homeomorphism from $(0,1)$ to $(0,\infty)$. And $x \to (x,\sqrt x)$ homeomorphism from from $(0,\infty)$ to the graph of $\sqrt x$ if you restrict $x$ to $x>0$. Compose these maps to get a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R$ to graph of $\sqrt x$.

Comment: Or exp is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R$ to $(0,\infty)$ directly.

Comment: @Milten Thanks, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Real line for example is homeomorphic to open interval $(0,1)$ which is bounded.

Comment: so we must remove point (0,0) from $\sqrt{x}$ then they are homeomorphic?