# Does there exist any continuous bijection between [0,1] and (0,1) and between [0,1] and IR?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, uniform-continuity

We know that there are bijections between $[0,1]$, $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$. But my question is can we obtain a continuous bijection between $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$, and between $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{R}$? 
I think there will not exist but I am not sure.

Comment: I do not know how to use mathjax,so please someone edit my question.

Comment: What is IR?${}{}$

Comment: Put them between dollars. `$\mathbb{R}$` gives $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Note:  $[0,1]$ is compact and $(0,1)$ is not

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42308/continuous-bijection-from-0-1-to-0-1)

Comment: @Clayton I think it's interval $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

The image of a continuous map of a compact metric space is compact.  In particular, the image of a continuous map of a compact metric space into $\mathbb R$ is closed and bounded.  Therefore, don't expect to find a continuous bijection between $[0,1], $ which is compact, and $(0,1)$, which is open.  Other explanations can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42308/continuous-bijection-from-0-1-to-0-1).

Comment: assuming the standard topology for $\Bbb R$

Comment: same argument applies for $[0,1]$ and $\Bbb R$, but there are continuous bijections between $(0,1)$ and $\Bbb R$