# How there are lots of points in $(0,1)\setminus I$?

Tags: real-analysis

I have some confusion in this answer 
link: [Continuous bijection from $(0,1)$ to $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42308/continuous-bijection-from-0-1-to-0-1)

[image]

My doubts: there are only two point in $ (0,1) - [0,1]= \{0,1\}$. But user Ihf said that there are lots of points?

My question How there are lots of points in $(0,1)\setminus I$?

Comment: The set $\ (0,1)$\I is even empty !

Comment: @Peter im not geting   How ?

Comment: $[0,1]$ is a superset of $(0,1)$ , there are no points left if we remove the larger set.

Comment: $I$ here is defined to be $[a,b]$ with $a$ and $b$ belonging to $(0,1)$; it is not the closed unit interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is unclear, $I$ is not the closed unit interval in this proof, but an interval defined earlier in the paragraph.

Let $x=\min\{a,b\}$ and $y=\max\{a,b\}$.  Then $(0,1)\setminus I=(0,x)\cup(y,1)$, which is uncountable.