# Determine whether $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ are homeomorphic or not

Tags: general-topology

I'm studying Gemignani's Elementary Topology. I need to determine that the open interval $(0,1)$ and the closed interval $[0,1]$ are homeomorphic or not when considered as subspaces of the real numbers with the absolute value topology.

My claim is that they're not. Suppose there was a homeomorphism $f$ from $(0,1)$ onto $[0,1]$. Then $f(c)=0$ for some $c\in (0,1)$. Now either $f([c,1))$ or $f((0,c])$ must contain $1$ otherwise $f$ won't be onto. Assume wlog that $f((0,c])$ contains $1$ then it follows by the intermediate value theorem that $f((0,c])=[0,1]$. But then $f$ cannot be one one, thus, a contradiction.

Are there better ways to prove that there is no homeomorphism without using the notions of compactness and connectedness? Also the author asks to find a "topological property" which one of the spaces has but which the other doesn't if the spaces are not homeomorphic. I'm not sure how to answer this using the proof that I gave.

---

Edit: Perhaps I got my answer to the last paragraph. *If $X,\tau$ is a topological space and $Y,Z$ are subspace of $X$ which are homeomorphic and  if every open subset of $Y$ is an open subset of $X$ then this must be true for $Z$ as well.* If not, there must be an open subset $U$ of $Z$ which is not open in $X$ then the image/inverse image of $U$ under the homeomorphism must not be open in $Y$.

In this case, every open subset of $(0,1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ but $[0,1]$ is open in the subspace topology of $[0,1]$ but is not open in $\mathbb{R}$. Please someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Your argument looks fine.  The "topological property" comment in the book is probably a reference to either connectedness or compactness, so I am not sure why you want to avoid mentioning those.  Note that the intermediate value theorem is really using the notion of connectedness even if it isn't phrased using that word.

Comment: @NateEldredge I am trying to avoid those because the author hasn't really discussed those topics yet.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/42310/589

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A property that $[0,1]$ has that $(0,1)$ has not not, is compactness, indeed. It's not one you use in your argument, though.

$(0,1)$ has the property "every point of $X$ is a cutpoint" (where a cutpoint (of a connected space) is a point $x$ such that $X\setminus \{x\}$ is not connected).

$[0,1]$ does not have this property, as $0$ and $1$ are not cutpoints, so for $[0,1]$ we can use : $X$ has two non-cutpoints. For $[0,1)$ we can use "X has one non-cutpoint", and so we can distinguish them too. Connectedness-related properties seem the most natural way to go here.