# Onto continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Is there exist a onto continuous function from (0,1) to (0,1]

Answer: Yes.

**My Attempt**:

Let $f: (0,1) \to (0,1]$ such that $f(x) = x$. This is onto itself but I know that if f is onto then Range $(f) =$ Codomain $(f)$. But in this case, It is not possible.

I'm unable to find such type of function. Please help me.

Comment: think about a quadratic which attains a maximum value of $1$ at $x=1/2$ and has zeros at $x=0,x=1$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42308/continuous-bijection-from-0-1-to-0-1/42310#42310

Comment: Codomain is semi closed interval. But codomain is closed in the link.