# continuous onto map from $(0,1)\to (0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

I need to know whether There exists any continuous onto map from $(0,1)\to (0,1]$

could any one give me any hint?

Comment: See also: [Continuous function from $(0,1)$ onto $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/167764) and other [question linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/167764).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hint**: $(0,1) = (0,\frac 12] \cup [\frac 12, 1)$. Can you map each part onto $(0,1]$?

Comment: No sir, I have no Idea

Comment: hint: $\times 2$

Comment: @TaxiDriver It's a disjoint union of semi-closed intervals.

Comment: Taxi: you have no idea how to send $(0,\frac12]$ continuously to $(0,1]$? Really no idea?

Comment: Yes $f(x)=2x$?????

Comment: @GitGud Ya, but nothing coming in my mind now how to use your hint

Comment: @TaxiDriver Yes, you do.

Comment: Now you've achieved "onto" you only need to maintain "continuous"

Comment: @TaxiDriver ... and now: can you map $[\frac 12, 1)$ onto $(0,1]$?

Comment: @Taxi Driver no, you're joking!

Comment: okay so Here is the Map $f(x)=2x; x\in (0,{1\over 2}]$ and $f(x)=1;x\in [{1\over 2},1)$

Comment: Hallelujah! $ $

Answer (score 6):

Find a polynomial that:

1. Crosses the x-axis at $x=0$ and $x=1$.
2. Has an absolute maximum of $f(x)=1$.

$$f(x)=-4(x^2-x),x\in(0,1)$$

Answer (score 5):

From The Hint of Martini  the Map $f(x)=2x; x\in (0,{1\over 2}]$ and $f(x)=1;x\in [{1\over 2},1)$ will work

Answer (score 4):

$f(x)=|\sin (\pi x)|$ will work

Comment: You can remove the absolute value since the function $\sin(\pi x)$ is positive on the interval $(0,1)$.