# Whether $(0,1)$ and $(0,1]$ are homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

In connection with the question [continuous onto map from $(0,1)\to (0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454040/continuous-onto-map-from-0-1-to-0-1/454051#454051) I would like to know whether $(0,1)$ and $(0,1]$ are homeomorphic. The map mentioned in the above question is onto but not a bijection. So does such a continuous bijection exist?

Answer (score 13):

HINT: For every $x\in(0,1)$, $(0,1)\setminus\{x\}$ is **not** connected. If $(0,1)$ and $(0,1]$ were homeomorphic, the same would be true of $(0,1]$, since connectedness is a topological property. Does $(0,1]$ actually have this property, or does it have some point that can be removed without disconnecting it?

Comment: @Sriti: That deleting any point leaves a space that is not connected. In other words, the question is: Is it true that $(0,1]\setminus\{x\}$ is disconnected for every $x\in(0,1]$?