# Projection of a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to one of the factors need not be closed.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, product-space

$\def\R{{\mathbb R}}$ 
May I please receive help with the following problem? It is from Munkrees Topology Textbook.

We know the projection to $X$ or $Y$ of an open subset of $X\times Y$ with the product topology is necessarily an open set.

(ii) Prove $X$ and $Y$ are compact topological spaces, then the projection of a closed set of $X\times Y$ to $Y$ is a closed set.

$\textbf{Solution:}$ If $\mu \subseteq X \times Y$ is closed, it must also be compact because closed sets in compact spaces are compact. Being the image of a compact set, $p(\mu)$ is compact. Because $p(\mu) \subseteq Y$ is Hausdorff, and compact sets of Hausdorff spaces are closed, $p(\mu)$ must be closed.

Comment: These look good.  Except: (ii) did not say Hausdorff.  (Unless you have Bourbaki definitions, where compact includes Hausdorff.)  But you say $Y$ is Hausdorff.  Why?

Comment: @GEdgar I was not sure about $(ii)$, I took a guess because I was thinking we can still find disjoint open sets in Y? i am not sure.

Comment: "Assume any topological space is both Hausdorff and non-empty, and any examples given must also be Hausdorff and non-empty."

Comment: You need not assume Hausdorffness at all for (ii).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others in the comments have said, your example for *i.* is good. I'd just be careful when you say

> $A$ is closed, and $p_2(A) = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ **is open (not closed)**

This could be construed to mean that *because* $p_2(A)$ is open, it is not closed. It's possible for sets to be both open and closed, so you may want to re-write it (this is very nitpicky).

---

Your proof of *ii.* is good, if a bit unclear. Because you say you're not sure about it, I'll spell it out in more detail with links to relevant theorems.

If $\mu \subseteq X \times Y$ is closed, it must also be compact, because [closed sets in compact spaces are compact](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/closed-sets-in-compact-topological-spaces). Being the image of a compact set, $p(\mu)$ [is compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874044/proof-that-the-continuous-image-of-a-compact-set-is-compact). Because $p(\mu) \subseteq Y$ is hausdorff, and [compact sets of hausdorff spaces are closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83355/how-to-prove-that-a-compact-set-in-a-hausdorff-topological-space-is-closed), $p(\mu)$ must be closed.

Comment: Thank you Noah, I made the change to my solution and just removed the part where i say (not closed), would that be fine?

Comment: Here, the relevant detail is that $p_2(A)$ is *not closed* (that's what the question is asking), so you would replace "is open (not closed)" with "is not closed." As I said, this is a tiny thing. Anyone reading this proof understands what you're going for.

Comment: I see, thank you, Noah. For part ii, I was given a link by. Henno, and I was wondering if what I added to my solution for ii.. is valid? Because I am still a bit confused.

Comment: There are two proofs going on here: 1. yours (and mine) which assume that $Y$ is hausdorff. *With this assumption*, your proof (just the first paragraph after **"Solution:"**) is correct. 2. You actually don't need the hausdorff condition (as Henno notes) this gives a slightly different proof.

Comment: Thanks, so what you provided and what I added for the ii is fine now? I deleted the two additional paragraphs

Comment: *if* you are assuming the spaces are hausdorff, that proof is fine. However, I notice that you've dropped that assumption ("Assume any topological space is both Hausdorff and non-empty") from the question, which now makes your proof incorrect (with the given assumptions). Hopefully the situation is clear.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of (i) is fine, your proof of why $A$ is closed needs work. For points in the plane with $x \neq 0$ your proof works to show we have an open neighbourhood (in $\Bbb R^\ast \times \Bbb R$ which is itself open in the plane so the neighbourhood is open in the plane too) that misses $A$, but for points with $x=0$ we need a separate argument. A closed set of $\Bbb R^\ast \times \Bbb R$ need not be closed in the plane, in general!

For (ii) This is true *without* Hausdorffness of any of the spaces while your proof assumes Hausdorffness in the codomain. The projection along a compact space is always closed and this characterises compactness; proofs can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/22764/4280), e.g.

Comment: Thank you Henno. I made the edit to the solution for the second part, as you indicated the proof for it. However, is the final paragraph needed for (ii)?