# Existence of a continuous surjection

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Does there exist a continuous surjection $f:(0,1]\to (0,1)$?

My try: Let $f(1)=a\in (0,1)$. So the map could not be monotone. Is that mean the image set must contain the maximum?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052470/continuous-function-from-0-1-onto-0-1

Comment: I thought that this question must be in mathstack but couldn't find. Thanks @StammmeringMathematician

Comment: You are welcome prof.